# Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {product})

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-functional-component

I have searched SO but I can't figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong. I haven't worked with functional components in react beyond simple examples so I need a little help. I have a parent component `Products`:

```
const Products = () => {
    const products = [{ name: 'Potatoes', price: '100', unit: 'KG' }, { name: 'Onion', price: '100', unit: 'KG' }, { name: 'Ginger', price: '100', unit: 'gram' }, { name: 'Ladies Finger', price: '100', unit: 'KG' }];
    return (
    <div>
      {
        products.map((product, index) => 
          <Product product={product} key={index} />
        )
      }
    </div>
  );
};

Products.propTypes = {};

export default Products
```

The above component renders the child `Product`:

```
const Product = ({product}) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <p>{product.name}</p>
    );
};

Product.propTypes = {};

export default Product
```

But I get the error

```html
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {product}). 
If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

The issue seems to be in my Parent component's return statement but I have no idea what. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i don't see any issue with this code

Comment: try logging `product` and check its type

Comment: @RameshReddy product is of type object. Also I removed the `<Product product={product} key={index} />` tag and put a console.log int its place, the code compiled without error. Not sure if that means the error is in my child component.

Answer (score 0):

Errors like `Objects are not valid as a React child` usually arise when your the interpreter misinterprets your syntax.
Try adding parentheses around the returned object in your map callback:

```
products.map((product, index) => (
          <Product product={product} key={index} />
))
```

Comment: I wasn't able do replicate your error in a new React project. I was able to display the product list correctly. Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please ?